MySQL Connector/NET (ADO.NET) PublicKeyToken
On my machine I installed mysql-connector-net-8.0.18 and connect with it (SSIS) to MySQL database. But this driver has some issues (cannot make some data previews because it wants to access non existing bogus_table) and I wanted to replace it with newer version mysql-connector-net-9.1 hoping to resolve this issue with preview. After upgrading connector I was not able to connect to my database anymore and was given some error about incorrect PublicKeyToken. Seems that my SSIS project has old key related to connector 8.0.18 and I need now new one for newer driver. (ADO.NET v2.4.0) (Visual Studio 2022 + SQL Server Integration Services Projects 2022)

What is going on here regarding these tokens?

Post the actual error message and the actual SSIS version you're using, and what you actually tried - did you try to create or modify an SSIS project? Or did you replace the driver version and expect the stored project to work? We can't guess what you're using and there's no ADO.NET v 2.4. You can't just use a newer assembly version with a .NET Framework app, including SSIS, if it requires an older one. The PublicKeyToken doesn't change from version to version.

MySQL Connector 9.1 works in SSIS - in fact I imported data from MySQL into SQL Server just 30 minutes ago.  To check whether the driver works open SSMS, go to the Import Data Wizard and select the MySQL .NET Framework adapter as source or target.

@PanagiotisKanavos error message and SSIS version

That error says the driver used by the package isn't installed at all. In .NET you can't just delete one assembly and add a new major version and expect it to be picked up. The easiest solution would be to edit the package and use the new driver. Theoretically you could use binding redirection by modifying the SSIS runner's app.config file but that risks causing problems if you don't understand how config files and redirection works
